# I need to set a where condition in crystal report through field formula

Tags: vb.net, crystal-reports

I need to set where condition in crystal report like
`count {table.support} where ({table.support} = "others")`

```
support
-------
others
others
myself
parent
others
```

The result should be 3.

How to do this in crystal report?  I'm new user of crystal reports.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The record-selection formula should be:

```
{table.support} = "others"
```

Answer (score 0):

Anything you place in record selection formula will be added in where condition by crystal reports.. so place your require condition in `Record Selection Formula`.

Comment: yes there is a `record selection formula` go to `Report ---> selection formula --> record` and write your code there